# how to stich together multiple test files in robot framework

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I have multiple test case files in robot framework so I want to run the test files and have logs. What would be the most efficient and maintainable way of running .robot files and having readable logs? I know you can put all the files in a folder and run pybot foldername but it's not very maintable in a sense that files need to be put in an order in my case so I m looking for somehting different and easy to maintaine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be maintaining them in a folder (test suite).

If you're worried about the [execution order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order) of the test cases/suites, you can prepend a prefix to the names. For example:

```
01__a_suite
|_____ 01__some_tests.txt
|_____ 02__more_tests.txt 

02__another_suite
|_____ 01__some_tests.txt
|_____ 02__more_tests.txt
```